# Engine with emphasis on strategic/positional analysis

Tags: engines, strategy, positional-play

Are there engines are especially recommended for strategic/positional analysis? I'm especially looking to use the engine in complex, opening position.

Comment: In earlier times, [HIARCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HIARCS) was always recommended for these kind of analyses. I'm not sure if it's up to date, though.

Comment: Yeah, I assume these things evolve and change a lot. I found an article from two years ago that recommended Komodo and then Houdini, while a few years ago it was Rybka...

Comment: No chess engine is good for strategic/positional analysis, you will need a chess coach.

Answer (score 2):

Chess engine is just a tool, your question is like asking which calculator your should use for learning mathematics.

An engine will just give you a score and a computer line, it tells you what you **should** play but it doesn't tell you what you **shouldn't** do.

You'll need to work hard, and use the engine to aid your analysis. Consider to pay for a human chess coach.

Comment: The intention of the question was if there are engines that tend to approach the positions from a more positional (or strategic) aspect. The comment below mentioned Komodo, and this seems to be a common perception. However, not sure if this is noticeable for ordinary humans or only on a very subtle level.

Answer (score 0):

Rybka has a "deep analysis" feature but it is still too hard for engines to do this work.  You might notice it recommends a move and evaluates the position as +1 or something and then if you play down the line a move or two it changes its mind and it is suddenly +0.

Answer (score 0):

The engine **Komodo** is supposed to be renowned for its positional bent, owing to its emphasis on evaluation over depth. GM Simon Williams mentions this in a YouTube video, and this is also reported on the [Wikipedia page of the engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Komodo_(chess)).

Unfortunately the engine is proprietary and currently goes for $99.